# Saving state of the Pokedex

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to write a code such that If I stop running the app and then run it again, the Pokédex will remember which Pokémon are caught and which aren’t by saving that state to disk. I wrote some code but I'm getting an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at "if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: self.pokemon.name) {" line of the code.
Here's my code,

PokemonViewController

```
import UIKit

class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {
    var url: String!
    var caught = false
    var pokemon: PokemonListResult!
    
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var type1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var type2Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var catchButton: UIButton!
    
    func capitalize(text: String) -> String {
        return text.prefix(1).uppercased() + text.dropFirst()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        nameLabel.text = ""
        numberLabel.text = ""
        type1Label.text = ""
        type2Label.text = ""

        loadPokemon()
    }

    func loadPokemon() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonResult.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                    self.nameLabel.text = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                    self.numberLabel.text = String(format: "#%03d", result.id)
                    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: self.pokemon.name) {
                        self.caught = true
                        self.catchButton.setTitle("Release", for: [])
                    } else {
                        self.caught = false
                        self.catchButton.setTitle("Catch", for: [])
                    }

                    for typeEntry in result.types {
                        if typeEntry.slot == 1 {
                            self.type1Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                        }
                        else if typeEntry.slot == 2 {
                            self.type2Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    @IBAction func toggleCatch() {
        caught = !caught
        UserDefaults.standard.set(caught, forKey: pokemon.name)
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: pokemon.name) {
            catchButton.setTitle("Release", for: [])
        } else {
            catchButton.setTitle("Catch", for: [])
        }
        
    }

}
```

Pokemon

```
import Foundation

struct PokemonListResults: Codable {
    let results: [PokemonListResult]
}

struct PokemonListResult: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

struct PokemonResult: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let types: [PokemonTypeEntry]
}

struct PokemonTypeEntry: Codable {
    let slot: Int
    let type: PokemonType
}

struct PokemonType: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instance variable `pokemon` is an implicitly unwrapped optional.

This line:

```
  var pokemon: PokemonListResult!
```

If you try to reference the variable pokemon before storing a value there, you will get exactly the crash you describe. Your code is trying to read a value from pokemon and it's nil. (`self.pokemon.name`). Don't do that.

(The code you posted **never** puts a value into your `pokemon` instance variable.)

Comment: Please help me with the code modification so that my goal can be reached.

Comment: It's your application. You're the one who knows how it's supposed to work. How is the instance variable `pokemon` supposed to be set? When the user selects a pokemon, should it set that variable?